# Path animation for image

Tags: raphael

I have to do some path based animation But the object which has to move over the path is **IMAGE** and **NOT** any **rect/circle** ...etc.

I am new to raphael.js and found no good documentation/demo regarding path animation for any external image.

For E.g.

```
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById('pond'), 500, 256);
var fairyPath = paper.path('M70,75 q-85,50 100,0 q200,-140 -100,0');
var fairy = paper.image("assets/fairy.png", 0, 0, 30, 30);
fairy.animate({path: fairyPath}, 3000);
```

How can i related fairy with fairyPath and create animation?

Comment: Here's an example you can probably use to help http://zreference.com/raphael-animation-along-a-path/

Comment: As i said; I need the example for IMAGE->PATH and NOT RECT/CIRCLE->PATH.

Comment: In the example links, instead of the rect name, just use the fairy name.

Comment: Did that before and was not working...But tried it once again and is working now...gotcha what was the issue..Thanks;